# hls.js control segment load order if maxBufferLength is large for low speed connections

Tags: html, video, video.js, media-source, hls.js

Each ts file is 5 seconds long, with a size of 2 mb each. A 512kb/s connection should be able manage and stream it without any hickups.

If one has a **maxBufferLength say of 30 seconds**, and one starts the player at say **minus 30 seconds** "livetime", the player will try to buffer up to 30 seconds.

When doing so, the player will **load almost all ts files** in the first playlist. For instance 20.ts, 21.ts 22.ts, 23.ts. Could be more or less.

The problem is that the **player loads all of them** at the same time.

Now if the user is on a **low speed connection**, say 1024kb/s the problem becomes obvious.

Rather than putting a **priority on the next ts.file** and load it in time **before** the previous file has finished playing the player would **choke** the internet connection completely, by loading 3-4 files asynchronously at the same time.

**Instead** of **needing 512kb/s** you now need an internet connection of **2-2.5 mb/s** to load a 512kb/s stream.

So my question is, **how can I force hls.js** to never load more than 1 ts file at the same time?

Is **there a configuration option** for this?